# How can I combine datadog io metrics in order to identify disk bottlenecks?

Tags: datadog

I am trying to create an alert in DataDog that would alert us when disk performance slows down our machines.

As a business requirement I would say that if the IO is almost saturated (over 90%) for more than 30 minutes, the alert should be triggered.

Here are the current set of metrics that are recorded:

`sys.cpu.iowait
system.io.avg_q_sz
system.io.avg_rq_sz
system.io.await
system.io.r_await
system.io.r_s
system.io.rkb_s
system.io.rrqm_s
system.io.svctm
system.io.util
system.io.w_await
system.io.w_s
system.io.wkb_s
system.io.wrqm_s`

[image]

It is possible to use any formulas to combine these, including SUM and AVG values.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These system.io metrics are reported from a [system agent check](https://github.com/DataDog/dd-agent/blob/5.6.3/checks/system/unix.py#L115-L133) that uses `iostat` under the hood.

According to the [iostat manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/iostat) one of the metrics `%util` (reported as `system.io.util` within Datadog) seems to do the job:

> %util: Percentage of CPU time during which I/O requests were issued to the device (bandwidth utilization for the device). Device saturation occurs when this value is close to 100%.

You can create a monitor, as a multi alert on host/device, when this metric is over 90 on the last 30 minutes on average, here is a current screenshot of such an example:

[image: example monitor in Datadog]

Of course one can also monitor other iostat metrics to identify other I/O performance failure modes.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer made this super obvious, but I had been searching around for awhile with no luck

Comment: I believe this remark about 100% utilization implying device saturation as reported by iostat is not anymore correct, at least for modern SSDs. See here: https://brooker.co.za/blog/2014/07/04/iostat-pct.html